# Creating a data frame of predictors and a factor vector

Tags: r, r-caret

In R-package 'caret' a dataset *mdrr* contains a dataframe with predictors and a vector factor *mdrrClass*.

```
require(caret)
data(mdrr)
```

How do I create a similar format for my own dataset where Pred1, Pred2, Pred3 in a data frame while the corresponding 'class' as factor? Say

```
x = data.frame(id = c("a","c","d","g"), 
          Pred1 = c(1,3,4,7),  Pred2 = c(1,3,4,7),  
          Pred3 = c(1,3,4,7),  
          class = c(1,3,4,7))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Now is your example different from what you want? I'm confused as to exactly what your question is here.

Comment: @MrFlick 

Sorry for the confusion. 

How do I create a similar format for my own dataset where Pred1, Pred2, Pred3 in a data frame while the corresponding 'class' as factor?

Comment: Just don't put "class" in the data.frame and then `myclass<-factor(c(1,3,4,7))`. ("class" is a special function name in R so it would be best not to have a variable with that name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `data(mdrr)`, R loads the file named "mdrr.Rda" which contains two objects, a data.frame (`mdrrDescr`), and an ordinary factor (`mdrrClass`).   There's nothing particularly special about either of these objects (except maybe that the length of the factor is the same as the number of rows in the data.frame).

If you want to create a package for which `data('myData')` loads two objects (say,'a' and 'b'), just save those objects to a single .Rda file:

```
save(a=myFavoriteDataFrame,
     b=myFavoriteFactor,
     file='path/to/my/package/data/myData.Rda')
```